# Browser color distinction between production and dev environment

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools

I use Firefox to develop and maintain a web application for my office. The interface will look identical for production & development, and the urls won't be easily distinct though except few digits in the middle.

Is there are hack or extension where I can assign Firefox to add thick red color bar(Top, address bar, corner etc) for specific websites ?

Comment: [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)